# How to run a jar file in hadoop?

Tags: java, jar, hadoop

I have created a jar file using the java file from [this blog](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hadoop-basics-creating) using following statements

`javac -classpath /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-core-1.0.3.jar -d /home/hduser/dir Dictionary.java`

`/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/jar cf Dictionary.jar /home/hduser/dir`

Now i have tried running this jar in hadoop by hit and trial of various commands

1`hduser@ubuntu:~$ /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar Dictionary.jar`

Output:

```
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

RunJar jarFile [mainClass] args...
```

2.`hduser@ubuntu:~$ /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar Dictionary.jar  Dictionary`

Output:

```
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Dictionary
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
```

How can i run the jar in hadoop? I have the right DFS Locations as per needed by my program.

Comment: The error says class not found. Make sure your jar has this class. Again your Dictionary class would need to have a main method in it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem. The problem is where you are creating the jar.

Basically, the directory that you are packaging into the jar is confusing the jar file in locating the main class file. Instead if you try doing :

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/jar cf Dictionary.jar /home/hduser/dir/Dictionary.class
```

i.e. package the class file specifically into the jar and then run:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar Dictionary.jar Dictionary
```

It just works fine provided that you have a main function in your class called Dictionary.

The problem is when you package a full directory inside a jar then the jar also needs to be aware of the directory structure to locate the class file. For this, we need to have a well defined package hierarchy to define the class location. So, when you are packaging `/home/hduser/dir/` into the jar, the jar is not aware of the location of the class file which is located deep inside this directory structure. For this you need to add a package name to your `.java` file according to the directory structure , for example `home.hduser.dir` and while running the `hadoop jar` command specify the class name with the package structure, for example `home.hduser.dir.Dictionary`.

Comment: I know that the command is: hadoop jar <jarFileName> <mainClassname> <AnyCommandLineArguements>.                                                When I am typing the <mainClassname> it is considered as <AnyCommandLineArguements> why is this happening? I am exporting my jar file using Eclipse as Runnable JAR>>Copy required libraries into a sub folder.
Please Help.

Comment: I got the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017899/how-to-run-a-class-from-java-jar-file-on-hadoop/43018453

Answer (score 10):

Use the below command to run the hadoop jar file from the **CLI**.

```
hadoop jar <jarFileName> <mainClassname> <AnyCommandLineArguements>
```

Comment: When I am typing the <mainClassname> it is considered as <AnyCommandLineArguements> why is this happening? I am exporting my jar file using Eclipse as Runnable JAR>>Copy required libraries into a sub folder.
Please Help.

Comment: I got the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017899/how-to-run-a-class-from-java-jar-file-on-hadoop/43018453

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into the same problem and the console does not show much information but just

RunJar jarFile [mainClass] args...

Please check the jar for the package folders location, as a straightforward approach please try is the package starts with com.company...

The "com" folder should be the first level folder when the jar is unpacked