# ClassNotFoundException while running wordcount jar file on single node single cluster hadoop file system

Tags: java, hadoop

I got an error like this while running my jar file on single node single cluster hadoop file system

The error I got:

```
hduser@jameena-X556UA:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar /home/jameena/Desktop/wordcountf/wordcountj.jar WordCountpro /usr/jameena3/inputdata/test.txt /usr/jameena3/outputwc
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCountpro
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Here's my code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class WordCountpro {
    //Mapper class
    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,Context contex) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line=value.toString();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                contex.write(word, one);
            }
        }
    }
    //Reducer class
    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)throws IOException,InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for(IntWritable val:values)
            {
                sum+=val.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf,"WordCountjob");
        job.setJarByClass(WordCountpro.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you made a mistake while making the jar file.Review that step.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012511/how-to-run-a-jar-file-in-hadoop

Comment: is your class is located in any package and can you tell me the way you created jar file

Comment: Actually My Source file WordCountpro.java  is loated in "Desktop/wordcountf" folder.. And i created the jar file in the same folder

Comment: Look if your class is located in any package then you need to m Benton full qualified name of your main  class like "packagename.WordCountpro" and it would be better if you could specify name of class with main method while creating a jar