# hadoop jar wordcount,jar wordcount exception

Tags: java, hadoop

Whenever I execute the command : hadoop jar wc.jar WordCount text.txt output
It gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

Even though everything seems to be fine

Can anyone help me out with this ??

Comment: Could you share the contents of WordCount and text.txt?

Comment: You need your Java class within a package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you need to make sure you have a main method inside the WordCount class.
You can also look at this answer right here: [How to run a jar file in hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012511/how-to-run-a-jar-file-in-hadoop)
As the answers suggest there's no problem when running the jar, but when creating the jar.
So for example, you need to run:

```
JAVA_HOME/bin/jar cf WordCount.jar WordCount.class
```

and then run

```
hadoop jar WordCount.jar WordCount
```

Hope this helps.